# ASP.NET MVC View not updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a login page (default ASP.NET MVC + styling) and no matter what I do in this page it keeps loading an older version of it. I even commented out all the code in view and it still loads. Deleted the view and it still loads. The issue is browser agnostic and deleting/disabling the cache doesn't help.

What I've tried so far was cleaning up the IIS Express websites, readding the Login page, checked applicationhost.config to see if there's something wrong there (looks ok).

Any ideas what it could be? Or possible fix?

The login.cshtml view was initially copied from another project (part of refactoring). I've checked the location of the file in the properties, I've checked if there are any other Login.cshtml in the solution.. Nothing.

Comment: had you rebuild code and cleared browser's cache?

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: _"I even commented out all the code in view and it still loads"_ - then you're not pointing the browser to a site running from the same directory as the one you're developing in.

Comment: @CodeCaster you're probably right. any ideas how to solve that? checked the virtual directory in iis express and looks ok. the project reference in the sln looks ok as well.

Comment: What browser are you using. If Chrome, press F12 and in the developer tool settings select disable caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was pointing to a previous version of the project I thought I had deleted. Checked the paths in the .csproj and they were referencing a folder other than the one where I had the latest version.
Thanks CodeCaster for pointing out the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in views don't trigger builds, and even if you only changed a view then build the project, it doesn't actually take in the change for some reason unless you also change a .cs file.

One thing I've had to do is every time i change a view i just add a `string asdf;` to the controller for that view, and if i change it again i just remove that field, and keep toggling between those states as i make changes to views.